# Xcode 4 project checked out from remote repository does not load

Tags: ios, svn, ios4, xcode4

I have an iOS project that I am working with on my iMac using the latest rev of Snow Leopard and Xcode/iOS SDK. The project is fully checked into a remote SVN repository (except for a couple of files such as the xcuserdata files).

However, when I check out the repository to my MacBook Pro (also latest Snow Leopard and iOS SDK), all of the files show up in the same directory structure as the iMac after I do the check out, but when I double click on the xcodeproj file, the name of the project shows up in the title bar of Xcode, and I get "No Scheme" in the scheme selector, "No Files" in the file browser, and "No Editor" in the editor window.

I am pretty sure that all references in the project are relative. Where do I start looking for the problem?